# I am trying to transfer data from S3 to Amazon Redshift using AWS Glue and an error occurs while calling o209.pyWriteDynamicFrame . What should I do?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am trying to transfer some data in CSV format from an S3 bucket to a table in Amazon Redshift using AWS Glue. However, my job fails with the following error:

```
Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; An error occurred while calling o209.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Exception thrown in awaitResult:
```

The job fails. However, I noticed that the schema is loaded into the Redshift table, but not the data.

I'm really not sure what is causing this error. I have checked the logs, but have not found any clues as to what might be going on. I have also queried `stl_load_errors` in my Redshift database to see if there are any loading errors. But the query turns up empty.

Here is the script for my Glue job:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue import DynamicFrame

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node Amazon S3
AmazonS3_node1704977097218 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"quoteChar": '"', "withHeader": True, "separator": ","},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3://smedia-data-raw-dev/google/"], "recurse": True},
    transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node1704977097218",
)

# Script generated for node Change Schema
ChangeSchema_node1705498745919 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=AmazonS3_node1704977097218,
    mappings=[
        ("resourcename", "string", "resourcename", "varchar"),
        ("status", "string", "status", "varchar"),
        ("basecampaign", "string", "basecampaign", "varchar"),
        ("name", "string", "name", "varchar"),
        ("id", "string", "id", "varchar"),
        ("campaignbudget", "string", "campaignbudget", "varchar"),
        ("startdate", "string", "startdate", "varchar"),
        ("enddate", "string", "enddate", "varchar"),
        (
            "adservingoptimizationstatus",
            "string",
            "adservingoptimizationstatus",
            "varchar",
        ),
        ("advertisingchanneltype", "string", "advertisingchanneltype", "varchar"),
        ("advertisingchannelsubtype", "string", "advertisingchannelsubtype", "varchar"),
        ("experimenttype", "string", "experimenttype", "varchar"),
        ("servingstatus", "string", "servingstatus", "varchar"),
        ("biddingstrategytype", "string", "biddingstrategytype", "varchar"),
        ("domainname", "string", "domainname", "varchar"),
        ("languagecode", "string", "languagecode", "varchar"),
        ("usesuppliedurlsonly", "string", "usesuppliedurlsonly", "varchar"),
        ("positivegeotargettype", "string", "positivegeotargettype", "varchar"),
        ("negativegeotargettype", "string", "negativegeotargettype", "varchar"),
        ("paymentmode", "string", "paymentmode", "varchar"),
        ("optimizationgoaltypes", "string", "optimizationgoaltypes", "varchar"),
        ("date", "string", "date", "varchar"),
        ("averagecost", "string", "averagecost", "varchar"),
        ("clicks", "string", "clicks", "varchar"),
        ("costmicros", "string", "costmicros", "varchar"),
        ("impressions", "string", "impressions", "varchar"),
        ("useaudiencegrouped", "string", "useaudiencegrouped", "varchar"),
        (
            "activeviewmeasurablecostmicros",
            "string",
            "activeviewmeasurablecostmicros",
            "varchar",
        ),
        ("costperallconversions", "string", "costperallconversions", "varchar"),
        ("costperconversion", "string", "costperconversion", "varchar"),
        ("invalidclicks", "string", "invalidclicks", "varchar"),
        ("publisherpurchasedclicks", "string", "publisherpurchasedclicks", "varchar"),
        ("averagepageviews", "string", "averagepageviews", "varchar"),
        ("videoviews", "string", "videoviews", "varchar"),
        (
            "allconversionsbyconversiondate",
            "string",
            "allconversionsbyconversiondate",
            "varchar",
        ),
        (
            "allconversionsvaluebyconversiondate",
            "string",
            "allconversionsvaluebyconversiondate",
            "varchar",
        ),
        (
            "conversionsbyconversiondate",
            "string",
            "conversionsbyconversiondate",
            "varchar",
        ),
        (
            "conversionsvaluebyconversiondate",
            "string",
            "conversionsvaluebyconversiondate",
            "varchar",
        ),
        (
            "valueperallconversionsbyconversiondate",
            "string",
            "valueperallconversionsbyconversiondate",
            "varchar",
        ),
        (
            "valueperconversionsbyconversiondate",
            "string",
            "valueperconversionsbyconversiondate",
            "varchar",
        ),
        ("allconversions", "string", "allconversions", "varchar"),
        (
            "absolutetopimpressionpercentage",
            "string",
            "absolutetopimpressionpercentage",
            "varchar",
        ),
        (
            "searchabsolutetopimpressionshare",
            "string",
            "searchabsolutetopimpressionshare",
            "varchar",
        ),
        ("averagecpc", "string", "averagecpc", "varchar"),
        ("searchimpressionshare", "string", "searchimpressionshare", "varchar"),
        ("searchtopimpressionshare", "string", "searchtopimpressionshare", "varchar"),
        ("activeviewctr", "string", "activeviewctr", "varchar"),
        ("ctr", "string", "ctr", "varchar"),
        ("relativectr", "string", "relativectr", "varchar"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ChangeSchema_node1705498745919",
)

# Script generated for node Amazon Redshift
AmazonRedshift_node1705498761115 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=ChangeSchema_node1705498745919,
    connection_type="redshift",
    connection_options={
        "redshiftTmpDir": "s3://aws-glue-assets-191965435652-us-east-1/temporary/",
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "dbtable": "public.google_test_2",
        "connectionName": "Redshift connection",
        "preactions": "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.google_test_2; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.google_test_2 (resourcename VARCHAR, status VARCHAR, basecampaign VARCHAR, name VARCHAR, id VARCHAR, campaignbudget VARCHAR, startdate VARCHAR, enddate VARCHAR, adservingoptimizationstatus VARCHAR, advertisingchanneltype VARCHAR, advertisingchannelsubtype VARCHAR, experimenttype VARCHAR, servingstatus VARCHAR, biddingstrategytype VARCHAR, domainname VARCHAR, languagecode VARCHAR, usesuppliedurlsonly VARCHAR, positivegeotargettype VARCHAR, negativegeotargettype VARCHAR, paymentmode VARCHAR, optimizationgoaltypes VARCHAR, date VARCHAR, averagecost VARCHAR, clicks VARCHAR, costmicros VARCHAR, impressions VARCHAR, useaudiencegrouped VARCHAR, activeviewmeasurablecostmicros VARCHAR, costperallconversions VARCHAR, costperconversion VARCHAR, invalidclicks VARCHAR, publisherpurchasedclicks VARCHAR, averagepageviews VARCHAR, videoviews VARCHAR, allconversionsbyconversiondate VARCHAR, allconversionsvaluebyconversiondate VARCHAR, conversionsbyconversiondate VARCHAR, conversionsvaluebyconversiondate VARCHAR, valueperallconversionsbyconversiondate VARCHAR, valueperconversionsbyconversiondate VARCHAR, allconversions VARCHAR, absolutetopimpressionpercentage VARCHAR, searchabsolutetopimpressionshare VARCHAR, averagecpc VARCHAR, searchimpressionshare VARCHAR, searchtopimpressionshare VARCHAR, activeviewctr VARCHAR, ctr VARCHAR, relativectr VARCHAR);",
    },
    transformation_ctx="AmazonRedshift_node1705498761115",
)

job.commit()
```

Any help on what is causing the error and a possible solution would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ther 'postactions' part in the glueContext.write_dynamic_frame. Take a look [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/sql-commands-redshift-glue-job)

The code should look like this:

```
AmazonRedshift_node1705498761115 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=ChangeSchema_node1705498745919,
    connection_type="redshift",
    connection_options={
        "redshiftTmpDir": "s3://aws-glue-assets-191965435652-us-east-1/temporary/",
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "dbtable": "public.google_test_2",
        "connectionName": "Redshift connection",
        "preactions": ...,
        "postactions": """
                BEGIN; insert into my_table select * from google_test_2; drop table google_test_2; END;
                       """

    },
    transformation_ctx="AmazonRedshift_node1705498761115",
)
```

**Also**, check the error logs for the task. Sometimes, the output logs may not have all the details about the errors.